# Universal app - view controllers -> one for each device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

so I am going to work on universal application for iOS soon. I've actually never done that so I am not sure what is the best practice here, but I have been able to think of some solutions instead of using separate VC for each device. The general issue is UI (transitions, positioning, animations etc.) as it varies for each device. I desperately wanna avoid duplicate logic code or creating some containers for logic as VCs are the place for logic. So here are my ideas:

- delegates - I would create protocol for each VC and then 2 classes implementing this protocol (containing logic specific to device) and in VC I would set the delegate to one of these classes based on device application is currently running on
- blocks - pretty much like delegates but way more messy
- inheritance - pretty much same as delegates but instead of protocol and 2 delegate classes and one VC there would be 3 VCs - 1. base 2. iphone 3. ipad - 2 and 3 would inherit from 1 and implement/override method specific to the device

These are 3 I can think of even if they are basically same but different implementation. I personally like delegates, but I am total newbie to this and I am asking for your advice. I am thinking about this in the right way or is there any other approach or best practice?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a Base view controller for all the code that applies to both iPad and iPhone, then a separate view controller for each that inherits from the base view controller.  That way you only have to override methods that contain device specific code, usually UI related code.

Comment: So you are up for inheritance then? Well sounds good. I still like the delegate approach (basically same as inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you don't really need to create different view controllers.

If you use storyboards, you can have a storyboard for common view controllers that are used by both iPhone and iPad and additional two storyboards for iPhone and iPad separately. Then you use IBOutlets to reference in your code.

Often you have more outlets in the iPad version, because the screen is bigger, but the code should still work in the iPhone version.

If splitting up the storyboards is not enough in your case, I would suggest using two categories in different files of a VC class. Then you keep the common code in the normal file and add specialised function code in the categories.

Comment: Yes, thats sure thing having 2 storyboards, but when it comes to (e.g.) animations, you have to do it for each device separately, these occur on certain events with certain data and in both cases (iphone and ipad) data and event are same but UI behavior is same, thats where I thought the delegate solution would come in handy, meaning the animation code would be in delegate and no matter what device you are on, the code invoking the animation doesnt care because the delegate is already the right one for the device, it just knows that by calling that method ....

Comment: .... certain animations modify UI for that action. I dont really see categories helpful in this case.

Comment: It allows you to have code associated to one class, your vc class, but have huge files.

Comment: I know what categories are, but I can't imagine how would I use them to solve situation I described.

Comment: In this case i would just use them to distribute the code. for instance in the (iPad) category I would have a 'pushAnimatedIPad' function and in the (iPhone) categiry I would have a pushAnimatedIPhone function.

Comment: What does it solve? I still have to decide in my logic which one to call (iPad or iPhone version) each time. Thats not solution thats just putting code in methods. My solutions at least limit that decision to single time (delegate class determination).